# Xcode 9 not finding React Native 0.56 or 0.57

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, xcode, react-native

I was working on my first React Native NativeModule. A simple 'Hello, World!' Objective-C function just to get an idea of how it worked. Things were going relatively smoothly, however, it seems xcode lost reference to all React Native files. I thought this problem was probably project specific, so I started a new TestApp using `react-native init TestApp`, but when I open that `.xcodeproj` file I have the same issue.

The first error in this new TestApp is in the `AppDelegate.m` file: `'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found` but as you might expect it avalanches from there.

I spent the most of yesterday trying out all sorts of potential solutions to no avail.

This might be a false lead, but maybe not, however I noticed `Header Search Paths` is empty whenever I first open `.xcodeproj` on a newly initialized project. That being said, I have tried numerous search paths based on answers I have found here on StackOverflow, GitHub, etc, the latest being `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/React`

I know this problem might be a little vague, but any help would be greatly appreciated. As an iOS developer, I am trying my best to be open to React Native, but continually running into issues such as this is really putting a damper on that.

Thanks!

ps. At this point I wonder if reinstalling xcode, node, npm, and react native altogether would be the surest solution.

**Edits for clarity**

First I run `react-native init TestApp` and `cd TestApp` followed by `npm install`. I've tried running `react-native link` at this point as well.

I then open `ios/TestApp.xcodeproj`. After xcode does its usual indexing I will inevitably be greeted by a red `'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found` in AppDelegate. Sometimes `'React/RCTRootView.' file not found'` happens too. Most of the time, even if this second warning doesn't happen, The `RCTRootView *` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is not colored.

If I try to create a native module like so:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface Test : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

I get an immediate `'RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`.

In other words, Xcode is not finding anything RCT. Autocomplete doesn't suggest anything RCT.

Even with these warnings, I can run the app from Xcode or by running `react-native run-ios`.

This extra bit, may or may not be relevant:

If I have `import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'` in my App.js, `NativeModules` turns out to be undefined.

My current feeling is that there is a crucial step in set up that is not listed in the RN Docs, and for some reason other tutorials aren't touching either. I tried on another computer to the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally linking native code with react-native!
So, I haven't really solved the precise issue, but I managed a workaround.

Previously I was trying to initialize a react-native project and then modifying the Xcode project that was built in the initialization.

I decided instead to approach the problem from the opposite angle of linking react-native to an existing xcode project by following this documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

I've been able to repeatedly link native code (both swift and objc) to react-native after `react-native init TestApp` by erasing the contents of `TestApp/ios` and following the process in the link above.

Thanks @Artal for providing some valuable info on the way it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

"Header search paths" being empty is perfectly normal. RN is exposing its headers from the `React` project. If you go to `React.xcodeproj` (under Libraries) you can see that the `React` target has a "Copy Headers" Build Phase, and these headers are being exposed when packaging the library as public headers.

To make sure that your app can use the headers, go to your app's scheme and into the `Build` section - the `React` target should be in the list and **before** your app's target. Also, the `Parallelize Build` checkbox needs to be OFF. It should be set-up like this out of the box in new RN projects, but maybe something was changed in your project so it's worth checking.

When the build is just starting, and especially on a freshly initialized project, you can expect to see some errors in the IDE during the build regarding public `React` headers, but they should be gone and resolved once all React third-party libraries finish building and React itself is packaged.

If everything is set-up correctly and it's still not working, delete the DerivedData folder and build again.

Comment: Thanks Artal, It's good to know blank header search paths is normal. A lot of questions regarding older versions of RN misled me a little.

Comment: If I build a new app with `react-native init TestApp` and open the xcodeproj it seems that everything is set up the way it should be, but it doesn't work. I can build and run the project just fine. The problem is that I cannot code. No RCT files are found. If I try to expose a function to RN, the app crashes saying the module is undefined.

Currently it feels to me like something is messed up outside the scope of any specific project.

It is the exact same problem with new projects as with the initial project I was working on.

Thanks again

Comment: Hey @RicardoNazario i'm a little unsure now what is the issue exactly. If you're saying that the app crashes then it's in run time issue, and not a compile/link issue, and in this case it's possible that something went wrong with exposing the new classes you've added. If that's the case it's impossible to know what went wrong without seeing the actual code, but it's also a little bit out of the scope of the question you posted..

Comment: Sorry, it was definitely out of the scope of the question and my current concern to bring that up.

The issue is this: When I open Xcode to develop a Native Module in Objective-C, Xcode doesn't find any of the React files. None of the react imports in AppDelegate work, and I cannot import RCTBridgeModule in my own module.

Comment: I just created a new project with `react-native init`, added a new native `RCTBridgeModule` and used it without an issue. You say that none of the react imports in AppDelegate work, but in your previous comment you said that you can build and run the project, so again - this is pretty unclear, which one is it? If it compiles and runs then what exactly doesn't work in AppDelegate? And if it runs - you should have no issue adding your own module, but it's confusing what exactly doesn't work, sorry

Comment: Hey Artal, I edited the original question with added explanation. I am able to be clearer there. Also, no need to apologize, I realize I am being unclear, and I greatly appreciate you taking any time to answer.